# How can I tell Entity Framework to save changes only for a specific DbSet?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Let's say I modify entities from different DbSets within a single DbContext.

How can I tell Entity Framework, when calling SaveChanges(), to save changes only for a specific DbSet?

Comment: You don't need other entity changes or you want them?

Comment: I want them but later (I cannot alter the way/order changes are made).

Comment: You can reject other `DbSet` changes and only save your specific `DbSet` change, but this way you will lose other `DbSet` changes.

Comment: Permanently or for that transaction only? Can you show me how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ideally, what you would do is just modify the entities you want to change, then call `SaveChanges()` then modify the other entities. However, if that is not possible I would add an overload of `SaveChanges()` that looks like this.

```
public int SaveChanges<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    var original = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(x => !typeof(TEntity).IsAssignableFrom(x.Entity.GetType()) && x.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
                .GroupBy(x => x.State)
                .ToList();

    foreach(var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => !typeof(TEntity).IsAssignableFrom(x.Entity.GetType())))
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }

    var rows = base.SaveChanges();

    foreach(var state in original)
    {
        foreach(var entry in state)
        {
            entry.State = state.Key;
        }
    }

    return rows;
}
```

Initially you find all entities whose state is not unchanged and save their entry. Then you set the state of every entity that isn't of your type `TEntity` and set their state to unchanged. Then call the `base.SaveChanges()` to save all changes to entities of your type.

Then, by looping through the saved entries, you can reset their original states back to them. This way you catch all adds/updates/deletes that aren't of your type, and restore them so that the next call to `SaveChanges()` doesn't lose their changes.

Comment: I think this will do the trick with some small changes, for example, when and object is created using proxy, this criteria ` x.Entity.GetType() != typeof(TEntity)` will not work. But I still think using multiple unit of work is a better option :) +1

Comment: I agree. Just making a new Context is by far safer, but messing with EF in ways you're not supposed to is somewhat of a strange hobby for me. :) I will change the type checking to what you have.

Comment: You can update this with some more modern C#: ".Where(x => x.Entity is not TEntity" rather than "x => !typeof(TEntity).IsAssignableFrom(x.Entity.GetType()))"

Answer (score 7):

Before using the below code, you should know if you want to save only a specific set of entities, then it means you should use different instance of your db context for that unit of your work.

But using this code you can reject changes of all entities except `YourSpecialEntity`:

```
db.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified &&
                            !typeof(YourSpecialEntity).IsAssignableFrom(x.Entity.GetType()))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(entry => {
                    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
                });

db.SaveChanges();
```

I suppose db is an instance of your dbcontext.

Comment: I see, so this would reset the values for the other entities.
What if I would hold references to the modified entries, change just the state to "Unmodified", save the changes for the current set, then change back the state of the references to "Modified"?

Comment: You can perform such job, but it somehow smells bad. I think the offer of using multiple unit of work is much better.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to EF and I had the same problem. In my storage program i e.g sumit only articleId and OwnerId for a new stock because i see no need for hidden fields in my mvc-form. At first EF created new entries in article and customer database, but i only wanted to insert a new item in the stocks table.
So the solution is quite simple:
For all entities you know you don´t want to save them  type this:

```
           //prevent Owner to be saved (again)
            db.Entry(stockItem.Owner).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

          //prevent article to be saved (again)  
           db.Entry(stockItem.ArticleItem).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

            db.Stocks.Add(stockItem);

           //now just the properties (-> dbset of the stockItem get´s saved)
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```